# How can I find out which Cocoa classes and APIs are portable across MacOSX and IOS?

Tags: ios, macos, portability

There are a number of useful business logic classes which seem to exist in both iOS and MacOSX (for example, `NSMutableDictionary`).

However as far as I can see the developer documentation does not indicate which they are - you're either using the Mac developer docs (in which case it will tell which version of OSX the API appeared in), or the iOS docs (in which case ditto for iOS).

Is there any documentation set (or alternative easy way) to find out which classes exist in both - i.e. the equivalent of "Available in iOS since version foo, OSX since version bar"?

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is that UIKit is for iPhone only, so any class starting with "UI..." wont be available on Mac (ex: UILabel, UITableView, etc)

Classes from the foundation Framework, starting with "NS..." are all available on MacOS, but not all are available on iOS.

In each class Reference documentation you have an "Availability" note at the beginning and sometimes a specific notes in the "Overview" section.

For example: NSAttributedString

Availability
Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.

Overview
iOS Note: In iOS, this class is used primarily in conjunction with the Core Text framework.

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: It's this 'availability' note that is annoying...depending on the doc set it seems to reference either Mac OSX v10.x or iOS x.y